# Applying Updates to Multiple Drupal Sites

Tags: drush, updating

I have over 100 drupal 7 websites on my single server. Applying updates to each site individually is a lengthy task.

Is there any simple way through which we can update all the websites at once, or can we use a single module folder for multiple Drupal websites?

Comment: Do they share the same Drupal installation? In that case, isn't `sites/all` exactly supposed to solve that? You'd still have to run database updates for each though.

Comment: every site is separately installed

Answer (score 1):

Please remember that *testing* is a very important part of every site upgrade.  It would not be difficult to write a script to copy code & db from live to stage for all sites, and then run *drush -y pm-update* on each site in turn; however, you should include a manual testing phase after the pm-update, and then push each tested site back to the live site as they are found to be working.

For the deploy step, you will want to copy the code from stage to live, and then run updatedb on the live site.  The live site should be offline during this operation.  See also [drush_deploy](http://drupal.org/project/drush_deploy) for scripting stage-to-live deployment.