# dev-test-prod staging workflow for drupal with transport of database changes

Tags: importing-exporting, workflows, staging

Hi I am looking for a best practice staging workflow for a four level staging environement for drupal:

dev->test->pre-prod->prod

I found this quite informative thread already [Applying Updates to Multiple Drupal Sites](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/43806/10320)

As the Teams will change especially on the test upwards it has to be pretty straight forward.

1. I guess we will move everting as far as posible through git or would rsync be better choice?
2. Is there some way to maintain some kind of central stage configuration where you just maintain the server adresses e.g. in on central place
3. How to move database changes without conflicting with productive content

Would be great if someone could share hints to some documentation of such a workflow.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi and welcome to Drupal Answers :) In it's current form this question is too broad to be answered, and is probably too localised to your specific situation to be useful for future visitors. Please consider breaking your questions down into ones that can be answered individually. Doing that will also make them more useful to future visitors without any extra effort

Comment: It's also one of the weakest features in Drupal right now...

Comment: Hi Clive, I understand your concern but separating wouldn't really help.  I did check out those two videos http://drupal.org/node/580026 and http://vimeo.com/33678298 which try to explain such a workflow, but they are not really easy to follow. 
Maybe someone already has written some kind of usable documentation about that.

Comment: No problem, it was just a heads up really. I've seen quite a lot of questions like these get closed as not-constructive/not a real question because they cover a lot of ground and they're quite difficult to answer succinctly/objectively. It's definitely an interesting question though; I hope you get a good answer, but as @MPD mentioned this is an area where Drupal falls disastrously short at the moment. The [Config Management Initiative](http://groups.drupal.org/build-systems-change-management/cmi) for Drupal 8 will help going forward but it's a bit of minefield in current/earlier versions

Comment: BTW these might be of interest: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33403, http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32659, http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1335, http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24777, http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21243. The last one there will probably be very useful, it's got a lot of links to deployment recommendations for Drupal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the meantime we do have a quite robust workflow and toolset for deploying Drupal through a multistage environment.

We use:
-Features, Strongarm and Drush on the Drupal side
-Jenkins, Git, Rsync for the Deployment

If you are interessted in further details just send me a PM

Answer (score 1):

Regarding #2, I would recommend using [drush site aliases](http://drupalcode.org/project/drush.git/blob/HEAD:/examples/example.aliases.drushrc.php).  See also the [sync_enable](http://drupalcode.org/project/drush.git/blob/HEAD:/examples/sync_enable.drush.inc) example in Drush, which demonstrates how you can get Drush to automatically adjust your database settings when you move your db from prod towards dev.  For moving configuration from dev to production, many folks use features; you might also want to look at [ctools export bonus](http://drupal.org/project/drush_ctex_bonus), which is built on much of the same technology.